# Verbs for sandpaper

Tags: verbs

What is the verb for applying a sandpaper? Or sandpaper itself is a verb? Possible candidates for me is apply, imply, use. Also, may I say that I smoothen something with a sandpaper.

Comment: Note that "sandpaper" is an uncountable noun.  I have **some** sandpaper.  I have 3 **sheets of** sandpaper.  But "I have **a** sandpaper" is incorrect

Comment: One minor note: *Smoothen* is very rare and old-fashioned in American English; we would just say *smooth* as in *use sandpaper to **smooth** the surface* or *I **smoothed** the wood with sandpaper*.

Answer (score 26):

What you're looking for is **sand.**  Merriam-Webster defines this verb as:

> to smooth or dress by grinding or rubbing with an abrasive (as sandpaper)

So in an example sentence like "You should use sandpaper on that block," it would be:

> You should **sand** that block.

Comment: or use "sand down" to remove some ambiguity.

Comment: @rackandboneman "Sand down" is only really used if there's a particular protrusion you're interested in removing by sanding. If it's a general smoothing/polishing you're after, it's just "sand": "sand down" would be out of place.

Comment: @R.M.: No, actually "sand down" [can mean either](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sand+down).

Comment: "Sand down" could be somewhat ambiguous to a woodworker as it's normally only used to mean removing imperfections or thinning / shaping (of some form). "Sanding" doesn't imply imperfections to the final form as it can be qualified as needed.

Comment: A rough surface is riddled with particular protrusions that have to be turned into non-protruding particles, that tend to end up on the floor, thus "down" :)

Answer (score 5):

The definition of sandpaper reveals a couple of verbs that go with it.

[Sandpaper](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sandpaper):

> paper covered on one side with abrasive material (as sand) glued fast and used for **smoothing** and **polishing**.

(Smoothen or polish something using a sandpaper)

> stiff paper that has a rough surface on one side and that is **rubbed against** something (such as a piece of wood) to make it smooth.

(Rub a sandpaper against a surface to smoothen it)

In fact, you can use *sandpaper* itself as a transitive verb. You can ***sandpaper***(v) a surface and make it smooth.

Depending on the purpose of the sandpaper, you could use [**abrade**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abrade).

> to rub or wear away especially by friction

You can also **scour** or **scrape** a surface using sandpaper.